# Killing all wineskin processes once an application ends on Mac OS

Tags: macos, terminal, kill

I am having a problem where c:\processes are still running after my applications end in wineskin.

I use wineskin to run all of my windows games on my mac and noticed just now that my mac was not cooling down.

An inspection of activity monitor showed me that processes with the location c:\ were still running and I know that obviously mac doesn't run these on its own.

Particularly, one of these processes was using 59% of CPU resulting in the heat up, even though I was done playing my games at least an hour beforehand.

Is there a way for me to tie these processes together so when dirt3_game.exe or whatever else ends, all of the constituent wineskin processes end too?
Or click a button that kills all these in one go after I'm done playing?
Is there a way to write a command in terminal, or a script or something that allows me to end all C: commands?

Just for reference a screenshot is attached so you can see these processes...[as you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Lkp8.jpg)

[image: desc]

Answer (score 0):

With the game running (or stuck), find out the name of the process looking in the Activity Monitor. Then using Script Editor, write a little applet that kills the process. Here's an example for Ghost Recon-

--Option A
try
    set pid_ to do shell script "pgrep 'Ghost Recon384054366Wine'"
    do shell script "kill -9 " & pid_
end try

--Option B
tell application "System Events"
    set PID_list to (unix id of every process whose name contains "Ghost")
end tell
repeat with x from 1 to (count PID_list)
    do shell script "kill -9 " & (item x of PID_list)
end repeat